# Docker - PG::ConnectionBad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Running Rails with Phusion Passenger, currently having trouble with postgres, whenever I run the build command I get this error:

```
 PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
     Is the server running locally and accepting
     connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
 ):
```

[My Dockerfile](http://pastebin.com/TF3VQkZT)

```
FROM phusion/passenger-customizable
MAINTAINER VodkaMD <support@nyvur.com>

ENV RACK_ENV="production" RAILS_ENV="production" SECRET_KEY_BASE="e09afa8b753cb175bcef7eb5f737accd02a4c16d9b6e5d475943605abd4277cdf47c488812d21d9c7117efd489d876f34be52f7ef7e88b21759a079339b198ce"

ENV HOME /root
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

RUN /pd_build/utilities.sh
RUN /pd_build/ruby2.2.sh
RUN /pd_build/python.sh
RUN /pd_build/nodejs.sh

# Custom instructions
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim nano dialog net-tools build-essential wget
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-client --no-install-recommends
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Generate SSL Certificate
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
# RUN openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt

# Enable Nginx and Passenger
RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down
# Enable Redis
RUN rm -f /etc/service/redis/down
# Enable SSH
RUN rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down
# Enable Postgres
RUN rm -f /etc/service/postgres/down

# Install bundle of gems
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile /tmp/
ADD Gemfile.lock /tmp/
RUN bundle install

# Copy application folder
RUN mkdir /home/app/Nyvur
ADD . /home/app/Nyvur
RUN chown -R app:app /home/app/Nyvur
WORKDIR /home/app/Nyvur
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

# Add a virtual host entry
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY config/nginx_configs.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/Nyvur.conf
ADD config/postgres-env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/postgres-env.conf

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/Nyvur/tmp/pids
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/Nyvur/tmp/sockets
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/Nyvur/log

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

EXPOSE 80 443
RUN bundle exec passenger start -p 80 -e production
```

[My docker-compose](http://pastebin.com/eGtRBDr4)

```
postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:9.4.4
  ports:
    - "5432:5432" # Bind host port 5432 to PostgreSQL port 5432
  volumes:
    - ./db/dumps:/app-db-dumps
    - ./db/postgres-setup.sql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
  environment:
    LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 3x1mpl3

mongo:
  image: mongo:3.0.7
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  command: --smallfiles --rest --auth

redis:
  image: redis:3.0.4
  ports:
    - "6379:6379" # Bind host port 6379 to Redis port 6379

web: &app_base
  build: .
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - .:/Nyvur
  links: &app_links
    - postgres:postgres.local
    - redis:redis.local
  environment: &app_environment
    # PostgreSQL Development Database:
    # DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:3x1mpl3@postgres.local:5432/App_production?pool=25&encoding=unicode&schema_search_path=public
    REDIS_URL: redis://redis.local:6379
    SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY: 5
    SIDEKIQ_TIMEOUT: 10
    ENABLE_DEBUG_SERVER: true
    RACK_ENV: production
    RAILS_ENV: production

worker:
  <<: *app_base
  ports: []
  command: sidekiq -c 25 -e production -q default
  environment:
    SECRET_KEY_BASE: e09afa8b753cb175bcef7eb5f737accd02a4c16d9b6e5d475943605abd4277cdf47c488812d21d9c7117efd489d876f34be52f7ef7e88b21759a079339b198ce
  environment:
    # SECRET_KEY_BASE:
    RAILS_ENV: production
```

[Full error log](http://pastebin.com/9UMZ4y03)

```
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /home/app/Nyvur/passenger.80.pid
Log file: /home/app/Nyvur/log/passenger.80.log
Environment: production
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
Problems? Check https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/standalone/troubleshooting/
===============================================================================
App 107 stderr: stdin: is not a tty
App 107 stdout:
App 107 stdout: I, [2015-12-17T17:34:39.223372 #107]  INFO -- : ** [Raven] Raven 0.12.3 ready to catch errors
I, [2015-12-17T17:34:40.413454 #127]  INFO -- : Started HEAD "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-17 17:34:40 +0000
App 127 stdout:
F, [2015-12-17T17:34:41.543651 #127] FATAL -- :
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `new'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  request_store (1.1.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  sentry-raven (0.12.3) lib/raven/integrations/rack.rb:61:in `call'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  passenger (5.0.22) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
  passenger (5.0.22) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:160:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (5.0.22) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
  passenger (5.0.22) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
  passenger (5.0.22) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'


I, [2015-12-17T17:34:41.559638 #127]  INFO -- :   Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.6ms)
I, [2015-12-17T17:34:41.566011 #127]  INFO -- :   Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.1ms)
I, [2015-12-17T17:34:41.572608 #127]  INFO -- :   Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
I, [2015-12-17T17:34:41.572727 #127]  INFO -- :   Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (20.2ms)
^CERROR:
Aborting.
```

Any help is really appreciated, I'm still getting the hang of Docker and working on production.

Comment: I think the application is assuming the database is available immediately. It can sometimes take a few seconds to start up. I would either have the application retry the connection a few times with a short delay, or create an entrypoint script to poll and wait for it to be available.

Comment: That makes sense, I found a script for that purpose, I'll use it again with the new changes and see how that goes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that it's trying to connect to a Unix domain socket points to a configuration issue in the Rails application.  Your `docker-compose.yml` has `DATABASE_URL` in it, but it's commented out -- uncommenting that should at least get closer (the application should at least attempt to start connecting to `postgres.local` instead of a local Unix domain socket which isn't going to exist since Postgres is running in a separate container).

Comment: Thanks a lot, made me realize something, I shouldn't be running passenger from the Dockerfile, since it would before any docker-compose container even fires. All working well, only got to work on nginx and I should be good to go :)