# Rails, Postgres and Docker having PG::ConnectionBad "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker-compose

I'm developing with containers and using docker-compose to lift them up.
From time to time I'll run `docker-compose down` and will rebuild the containers. Most of the times I get this error

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
     Is the server running locally and accepting
     connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
 ):
```

I don't get why Rails is complaining about Postgres not being there, if the entire containers are *being rebuilt again*. Also, the error just disappears after a while, without me doing anything other stopping, re-upping or rebuilding the containers.
I moved over to developing with containers to precisely escape from annoying issues like this.

This are the contents of my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  users:
    build:
      context: '.'
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
     - ".:/app/users/"
    working_dir: /app/users
    command: [rails, server, -p, "3000", -b, 0.0.0.0]
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: somedb
      POSTGRES_USER: someuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somepass

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - "redis:/var/lib/redis/data"

volumes:
  redis:
```

`database.yml`

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: somedb
  user: someuser
  password: somepass
  host: postgres
  port: 5432
```

Am I missing extra configurations on the postgres service or is it related to the users container?

Comment: Did you solve this ever?

Comment: @creimers not exactly. See accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, and sadly, the problem went away when `down`ing the containers and building them again.

Answer (score 1):

Add in docker-compose.yml users

```
 version: '2'
 services:
   users:
    environment:
        DATABASE_URL:postgres://user:pass@postgres:5432/datex_dev?pool=5&encoding=utf-8
   ....
```

Add in database.yml

```
 development:
   <<: *default
   url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>  
   ...
```

See [Docker - PG::ConnectionBad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340985/docker-pgconnectionbad)