# Postgresql DB not getting connected in docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

My rails application is running in docker. I am having my server running and listening on host 'localhost' and port 3000. But when I hit the browser with 'http://localhost:3000/' I get the below error-

PG::ConnectionBad at /

could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "db" (184.168.221.24) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I am unable to find out from where this '184.168.221.24' IP is coming.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you start your containers via compose? This looks like you have a linked `db` container. Containers run on a virtual network on your machine

Comment: Yes  I am running 'sudo docker-compose up' for server start.

Comment: Well it looks like your `db` container is either not starting up properly or not allowing connnections from your app container. Can you verify that your `db` container is running (`docker ps`). And did you `expose` port 5432 on your `db` container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

`docker restart container-name`

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

This will restart your PostgreSQL, hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: got this
postgresql: unrecognized service

Comment: try this `sudo yum install postgresql-server`

Comment: No he wants to run it in a compose stack. Not install it on a local machine

Comment: Hey Mayur, when I run this 'psql --version', I got this 'psql (Postgres-XC) 1.1
(based on PostgreSQL) 9.2.4'. That means postgresql-server is installed on my machine. Right?

Comment: What about restarting  `docker-machine restart dev` or `boot2docker stop`
`boot2docker start`

Comment: @HarshwardhanSinghRathore can you please post `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: version: '2'

services:
  bundle_cache:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - /bundle_cache

  db:
    image: mdillon/postgis:9.6
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  web:
    build: .
    command: ./docker-start.sh
    environment:
#      APIPIE_RECORD: examples
      BUNDLE_PATH: /bundle_cache
      DATABASE_POOL: 5
      WEB_CONCURRENCY: 1
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - .:/yogassential
    volumes_from:
      - bundle_cache

Comment: @HarshwardhanSinghRathore let me try

Comment: @HarshwardhanSinghRathore please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196409/docker-rails-app-cannot-connect-to-linked-postgres-container-doesnt-seem-to

Comment: Checked, I have already  mentioned host: db in my database.yml under development. But unfortunately...

Comment: Okay @HarshwardhanSinghRathore let's  Add users in docker-compose.yml  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340985/docker-pgconnectionbad

Comment: Thanks Mayur. Got some help from above link. I added postgres:
  restart: always in docker-compose.yml that restarted postgresql server in the docker at the time server start. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HarshwardhanSinghRathore vote up and make is correct :D this is the best way for thank you.

Comment: Edit your comment with this 'docker restart container-name' and I will vote up. Because we need to restart psql server in docker. :D

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in the comments, it looks like your `db` container is either not starting up properly or not allowing connections from your app container. Verify that your `db` container is running (`docker ps`). Further, ensure that you `expose` port 5432 on your `db` container to other containers in your compose stack.

Comment: DB container is running with image - mdillon/postgis:9.6

Comment: Then it is most likely because port 5432 is not exposed. You can use `expose: 5432` in your compose yaml to open it to linked containers. [Docu](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose)

Comment: This is what I am having in docker-compose.yml file-  

db:
    image: mdillon/postgis:9.6
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'

Comment: Any other way to expose: 5432 ?